# Access variables from another module by their name

Tags: python, variables, dynamic, global-variables

I have a module `A.py` where I declared all the variables needed:

```
dog_name = ''
dog_breed = ''
cat_name = ''
cat_breed = ''
# .....
```

I have a file B.py where I import A. I know how to access the variables I defined in A:

```
import A 

A.dog_name = 'gooddog' # I am able to use A in file B
A.cat_name = 'goodcat'

print(A.dog_name) # this is working fine
```

But I would like the user to enter the name of the variable he wants to access, for example 'cat_name' or 'dog_name'.

```
x = input('Which variable do you want to read') # could be cat_name or dog_name

# This fails:
print(A.x) # where x should resolve to cat_name and print the value as goodcat
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you done any research? Also, please take a look at [ask].

Comment: yes I did. I am not able to get the values. A.x is giving me variable not available error. I am not able to tell to resolve the value of x.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getattr` with modules:

```
import A

getattr(A, 'dog_name')
# ''
```

and `setattr`, as well:

```
setattr(A, 'dog_name', 'fido')
getattr(A, 'dog_name')
# 'fido'
```

Comment: Super. Thank you very much.